# Strange behaviour when passing variable down to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am seeing some strange behaviour when I am trying to pass down a variable to a child component in react.  When I `console.log` just before the return statement `(so console.log(1))` in the parent component the data is correct, however when I `console.log` in the child component `(so console.log(2))` the data has changed??

I have a suspicion that it relates to the `randomSelect()` function but again when console logging out this looks to only be called twice (as expected).

I have pasted a 'playerOneId' in directly (avoiding using the `randomSelect()` function) and the data shows correctly in the child component when doing this, hence my suspicion around the `randomSelect()` function.  It could be unrelated but not sure.

A gold medal to anyone can answer this one as it has had me for hours now and I've run out of ideas.

PARENT COMPONENT:

```
const Board = () => {

const [starships, setStarships] = useState([]);
const [playerSelected, setPlayerSelected] = useState(false);
const [result, setResult] = useState('');
const [playerScore, setPlayerScore] = useState(0);
const [computerScore, setComputerScore] = useState(0);

const STARSHIP_QUERY = `{
        allStarships {
            starships {
                id
                name
                starshipClass
                maxAtmospheringSpeed
                costInCredits
                passengers
                filmConnection {
                    films {
                        title
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
`

useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://connectr-swapi.herokuapp.com/', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify({query: STARSHIP_QUERY})
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => setStarships(data.data.allStarships.starships))
    .catch(error => console.log({'Error': error}))
    
},[])

const randomSelect = () => {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * starShipIds.length);
    const selectedId = starShipIds[random];
    return selectedId;
}

const starShipIds = starships.map(ship => ship.id)    
const valueOneID = randomSelect();
const valueTwoID = randomSelect();
const playerOneId = valueOneID;
const computerId = valueTwoID;
const playerOneShip = starships.filter(ship => ship.id === playerOneId) ;
const computerShip = starships.filter(ship => ship.id === computerId);


const catergorySelect = (key, value) => {

    let computerValue = key === 'filmConnection' ? computerShip[0][key].films.length : computerShip[0][key];

    if (value > computerValue) {
        setResult('You Win!');
        setPlayerScore(playerScore + 1)
    }

    if (value === computerValue) setResult('You Draw!');

    if (value < computerValue) {
        setResult('You Lose!');
        setComputerScore(computerScore + 1)
    }

    setPlayerSelected(true);
}

console.log(1, playerOneShip[0]); // data is showing correctly

return (
    <div className="background">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12 col-sm-4">
                {playerOneShip.length &&
                    <GameCard 
                        ship={playerOneShip[0]} // data passed in
                        player='player-one'
                        select={catergorySelect}
                    />
                }
                {playerSelected &&
                    <Score 
                        score={playerScore}
                        colour="white"
                    />
                }
            </div>                
            <div className="col-12 col-sm-4">
                <div className="row">
                    <h1>{result}</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <DefaultBtn 
                        text="START AGAIN"
                        colour="white"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>                
            <div className="col-12 col-sm-4">
                {playerSelected && 
                    <React.Fragment>
                    <div>
                    {computerShip.length &&
                        <GameCard 
                            ship={computerShip[0]}
                            player='computer'
                            catergorySelect={catergorySelect}
                        />
                    }
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Score 
                            score={computerScore}
                            colour="white"
                        />
                    </div>
                    </React.Fragment>
                }
            </div>   
        </div>              
    </div>
)
}
```

CHILD COMPONENT:

```
const GameCard = props => {

const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);
const [disableCategory, setDisableCategory] = useState(false);

const {
    ship,
    player,
    select,
} = props;

console.log(2, ship) // different data is showing

const categories = Object.entries(props.ship).map(([key, value], index) => {
    const choosenCategory = selected === index ? 'selected' : '';
    const disableButton = disableCategory ? 'disable' : '';

    switch (key) {
        case 'maxAtmospheringSpeed':
            return <li className={`card ${player} ${choosenCategory} ${disableButton}`} onClick={(() => { select(key, value); setSelected(index); setDisableCategory(true)})} key={index}>{`Maximum Speed: ${value}`}</li>
        case 'costInCredits':
            return <li className={`card ${player} ${choosenCategory} ${disableButton}`} onClick={(() => { select(key, value); setSelected(index); setDisableCategory(true)})} key={index}>{`Cost In Credits: ${value}`}</li>
        case 'passengers':
            return <li className={`card ${player} ${choosenCategory} ${disableButton}`} onClick={(() => { select(key, value); setSelected(index); setDisableCategory(true)})} key={index}>{`Number Of Passengers: ${value}`}</li>
        case 'filmConnection':
            return <li className={`card ${player} ${choosenCategory} ${disableButton}`} onClick={(() => { select(key, value.films.length); setSelected(index); setDisableCategory(true)})} key={index}>{`Number Of films: ${value.films.length}`}</li>
        default:
            return null
    }
});

return (
    <div className="card">
        <img className="card-image" src="assets/img/starships/2.jpg" />
        <div className="card-body">
            <p className="card-title">{`Ship Name: ${ship.name}`}</p>
            <p className="card-sub-title">{`Class: ${ship.starshipClass}`}</p>
            <ul>
                {categories}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a reference issue, the variable passed in props is updated by another render in the parent.

A way of fixing it could be to put all this section of code in a useEffect depending on the loading of the starships:

```
const starShipIds = starships.map(ship => ship.id)    
const valueOneID = randomSelect();
const valueTwoID = randomSelect();
const playerOneId = valueOneID;
const computerId = valueTwoID;
const playerOneShip = starships.filter(ship => ship.id === playerOneId) ;
const computerShip = starships.filter(ship => ship.id === computerId);
```

It could look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const starShipIds = starships.map(ship => ship.id)    
    const valueOneID = randomSelect(starShipIds);
    const valueTwoID = randomSelect(starShipIds);
    const playerOneId = valueOneID;
    const computerId = valueTwoID;
    setPlayerOneShip(starships.filter(ship => ship.id === playerOneId));
    setComputerShip(starships.filter(ship => ship.id === computerId));
    
},[starships])
```

For this you need to create a state for player ship and computer ship and replace previous usage of these, like in my example above.

Also, you should pass the starship ids to random select as a parameter and not use a const and assume it has the correct value because it is in the scope of the function.